# How to transform a field in a sql statement?

Tags: sql

I want to transform a field from my SQL Query, depending on the value of that field.

For example, if a field called "class" has a value of 1, the output should be "First Class". What can I do in SQL to make it bring back "First Class" instead of 1 in my result set?

Comment: You haven't said what you want to use this for, but it may be a better design to do what you require in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 'first class'
       ELSE 'second class' -- or whatever you want to output in the != 1 case
       END as TransformedColumn,
       col2,
       -- etc...
FROM myTable
```